# Azure Websites Application Insights - switching config

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Website.  For the sake of this question, the production version of the website runs on `example.com`, and a test version of the website runs on `sandbox.example.com`.

The only difference between the two is that they have different configuration.

At present, they are running under different websites, and I deploy the same website to each azure website via git.

I'd like to separate out the Application Insights data.  Is there a technique or process that anyone uses - apart from editing the `ApplicationInsights.config` file in the sandbox environment post deploy?

Or would using a deployment slot handle this in some way?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There was a new blog post about exactly this today: [Application Insights Support for Multiple Environments, Stamps and App Versions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions.aspx).

> The destination of the telemetry is determined by the instrumentation
>   key (iKey), which is sent along with every telemetry message. In the
>   Application Insights portal, similar events and metrics with the same
>   iKey are aggregated to give you charts of average durations, event
>   counts, the sum of users, and so on. The iKey appears in two places in
>   your project. One is in `ApplicationInsights.config`:
>   `<InstrumentationKey>94843456-2345-3456-4567-324562759284</InstrumentationKey>`
>
> If your application has web pages, the iKey also appears in a script
>   in the head of every web page. Usually, it’s only coded once in a
>   master page such as `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.
>
> To direct telemetry to different application resources, we can create
>   several resources with different iKeys. Then we only have to change
>   the iKeys in the application at each transition in its lifecycle –
>   along with other configuration data such as connection strings,
>   certificates, and subscriptions.

The article then goes on how to do this in code, confg, etc:

> 1) Add `iKey` as a property in `Web.config`:
>
> 2) Instead of using the `iKey` from `ApplicationInsights.config`, we’ll
>   set it in the code. In `global.asax.cs`.
>
> To avoid confusion, remove the `<InstrumentationKey>` node from
>   `ApplicationInsights.config`.
>
> 3) Configure the web pages to pick up  `instrumentationKey: "@Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey"`. This is
>   the script usually found in `View\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.
>
> 4) Don’t forget to update your `Web.config` with appropriate `iKey`
>   configuration during the deployment process. You might devise a way of
>   setting it appropriately as part of your build, but I’ll leave that to
>   you.

Comment: This is precisely what I need.  I am curious to know if this was an existing feature that wasn't documented (or hard to find) or if it's something new?

Comment: I think most of the stuff in the blog post is stuff you could have done for a while, just not documented anywhere yet.  at least by my read

Comment: Link is dead, here is another to the same content- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/

Answer (score 3):

Found this semi-related question: [How to support multiple Azure subscriptions for a single application with application insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206673/how-to-support-multiple-azure-subscriptions-for-a-single-application-with-applic) this is for using by cloud services, and it works!

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appInsightsKey"];
```

I have done this in my unity registertypes method, it works there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JTG is this a better answer?

Comment: I understand you cannot comment yet and that maybe frustrating, but that doesn't mean the answer section becomes a impromptu comment section for those who don't have enough rep.  Rep locking comments is the best way for SO to stop spam.  Ask good questions and/or post good answers and you will easily get the 50 rep points needed to contribute.

Comment: i know the reasons for the reputation system, and yes was a bit frustrated and i was rambling i my "answer" ... have cleaned it up to provide an answer to the question....

Answer (score 2):

In the Azure portal for websites, on the config tab there is a section called App Settings.  You can put your different configuration settings here.  When publishing, azure will inject those settings into web.config.

Then just use WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings as you would normally and it will pull the injected values.

Comment: Yes - but the Application Insights configuration is not in `web.config`, but rather `ApplicationInsights.config`.

Comment: Sorry, missed that point.  Looks like you can configure applicationinsights.config per build configuration.  Here's a link...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn550723.aspx