# Request tracing with Application Insight of a ASP.NET WebApi running on Service Fabric

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I'm currently trying to setup Application Insights for a WebApi running on Service Fabric. While this is super easy to configure for a .NET Core application, it seems to be way more complicated for a .NET Classic application.

The official docs do only contain a rather primitive way to setup Application Insights by clicking through Visual Studio  - which in the end did not work for me (it tried to add a reference to the .NET Core Nuget Package for Application Insights).

### Important facts about the project

- TargetFramework is net461
- The application is running on Service Fabric 6.5.664.9590

### What i tried so far

In my project, i referenced these three nuget packages:

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector

Content of the **ApplicationInsights.config** (I added it to the root of the project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
  </TelemetryModules>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

In **Startup.cs**, i overwrite the instrumentation key - because it differs based on the environment the application is running on (read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609966/2492458))

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc();

     services.AddAuthentication(...);

     TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = _applicationInsightSettings.InstrumentationKey;
}
```

However - no request traces or any other information is sent to Application Insights. What am I missing?

***Edit***

The configuration part is working - when debugging the app, I can see that the `TelemetryInitializers` property in `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is set to what i configured in `ApplicationInsight.config`. But nothing is being sent to ApplicationInsights and there are also no errors or exceptions happening.

***My solution***

Turns out the easiest solution was to get rid of the `net461` target framework constraint. A dependency I used (a NuGet package) was limiting me to use `net461`. Once I got rid of that dependency, and moved the application to .NET Core and boom - everything works just magically.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric) documentation too?

Comment: Yes - I copied the example and installed the nuget packages mentioned, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you run on a different network to see if there might be a firewall blocking your traffic?

Comment: I tried to run the app on different networks (home network, hotspot from my phone) but none of them worked. Also I did not get any debug outputs from ApplicationInsight - you usually get them when it send something over the network. However - i fixed it by switching to .NET Core.